# Finding the entities of a CoreData model at runtime

Tags: swift, macos, core-data, nsentitydescription, nsmanagedobjectmodel

I have an macOS app being developed in Xcode (8.3.2) in SWIFT.

I have a CoreData model with a number of entities and an identifier (myidentifier).

I want to be able to identify the entities of the model programatically at runtime so that I can iterate through the entities and store data being sourced from a range of JSON files based on the data within the JSON file.

To date I have been creating entities and then writing a class for each entity to both save and fetch the data.  It is working perfectly and as expected.  However, if I continue like this I will end up with about 50 different entities and their associated class files (note that some while entities use a one to many relationship, the majority do not).

I would like to create a single class that will enumerate through the numerous entities of the model and store the relevant data (as well as its associated fetch routine).

I should also note that I am using NSManagedObject subclasses for each of the entities.

How do I obtain a NSManagedObjectModel reference to the model that I am using for the app?  I can't seem to find the right mechanism to allow me to do this.  Can I do this using the model identifier?

My thinking is that if I can then use entitiesByName I can make use of the resulting [String: NSEntityDescription] to then access my entities and enumerate as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `mergedModel(from bundles: [Bundle]?)` (see the [documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectmodel/1506704-mergedmodel), specfying `Bundle.main` to get the main bundle.  Alternatively, your NSManagedObjectContext will have a reference to the `persistentStoreCoordinator` which will itself have a reference to the `managedObjectModel`.

Note that NSManagedObjectModel has an `entities` property so you can use:

```
for myEntity in myModel.entities { ... }
```

rather than using `entitiesByName`.

Comment: Brilliant thanks.  I solved it using the following: '        let contextTCCEDJ = self.container.viewContext
        let test = contextTCCEDJ.persistentStoreCoordinator?.managedObjectModel'